# (XSLT, Code optimization) How to output the nodes refering to the value of sibling-nodes ..?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am transforming XML to XML using XSLT, The objective is to read the value of tag `<node1>`, if it is null then it must be assigned with the value of `<node2>`, if incase `<node2>`, is also null, then default text "Default" has to be assigned .. to both tags ..

**EDIT:** If `<node2>`is null and `<node1>` isn't .. then the code shouldn't update `<node2>` with `'Default'` text but it has to be transformed as it is ..

This is the test XML I am trying with:

```
<root>
    <node1></node1>
    <node2></node2>
  <parent>
    <node1>data1</node1>
    <node2></node2>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <node1></node1>
    <node2>data2</node2>
  </parent>
  <parent>
    <node1>data1</node1>
    <node2>data2</node2>
  </parent>
</root>
```

And this the XSLT code I have designed:

```
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="template1" match="node2[(following-sibling::node1[.='']|preceding-sibling::node1[.=''])]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test=".=''">
        <node1><xsl:text>Default</xsl:text></node1>
        <node2><xsl:text>Default</xsl:text></node2>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <node1>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </node1>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="template2" match="node1[.='']"/>
```

Though my code works, I am not happy with its bulkiness of the code .. Is there anyway to get rid of redundant (if any) lines .... And is there any alternative to use 2 templates to accomplish this (namely template1 and template2), is it possible to reduce the number of templates?

Comment: I personally liked Tomalak's sol .. it satisfies much of the requirement .. It looks cool and a lot of technical .. I can write code for my requirements (may not be 100% efficient ones) but his code is worthy .. so accepted .. ;-)

Comment: I have posted my own answer too .. That will satisfy the needs ..

Comment: There is an answer from me and it may be worth your attention :)

Comment: @Dimitre, I have accepted your answer ..

Comment: You are welcome -- so far you've been posting very interesting questions

Comment: @Dimitre, thank you, I am really feeling glad .. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vReplacement">Default</xsl:variable>

       <xsl:variable name="vRep" select=
        "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='vReplacement']/text()"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="node1[not(node())] | node2[../node1[not(node())]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="../node2/text() | $vRep[not(current()/../node2/text())]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**It is shorter and simpler** than the current solutions -- 7 lines less and, **more importantly, one template less** than the currently selected solution.

**Even more importantly**,  this solution is completely declarative and push-style -- no calling of named templates and the only `<xsl:apply-templates>` is in the identity rule.

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node1[not(node())] | node2[../node1[not(node())]]">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:sequence select="(../node2/text(), 'Default')[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Using the power of XPath 2.0 sequences this solution is quite shorter than the XSLT 1.0 solution**.

**Something similar is not possible in XSLT 1.0** (such as selecting the first of the union of two nodes without specifying predicates to make the two nodes mutually exclusive), because the node with the default text and the node1/node2 nodes belong to different documents and, as we know well, node ordering between nodes of different documents is implementation specific and is not guaranteed/prescribed.

**This solution is completely declarative** (no if/then/else) and completely push style: the only `<xsl:apply-templates>` is in the identity rule.

Comment: This is what I was really looking for .. :-)

Comment: @Dimitre, I need a small clarification with XSLT 1.0 solution, Why do we need to declare one more variable (namely $vRep) and assign the value of the variable $vReplacement. Where as direct usage of $vReplacement gives an error (!) (I had tried this, long time back too) .. what would be the reason behind the error? Is that the bug with XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @infant-programmer: I want to use the <xsl:variable> as a *node*, not as value, because the union operator "|" is defined only on nodes. In XSLT 1.0 a reference to a variable gives us just the value of the variable. Unfortunately, if the value nas nested children elements, it is of the infamous RTF (Result Tree Fragment) type and its innards cannot be manipulated with XPath. There are three ways out of this: 1. Use a namespaced child node of xsl:stylesheet (with global scope). 2. Use an xsl:variable as a node (my choice here) and 3. Use the xxx:node-set() extension function.

My choice: (2)

Comment: @infant-programmer: More information about the RTF type: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments and http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200304/msg01234.html

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node1[.=''] | node2[.='']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="GetOwnValue" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetOwnValue">
    <xsl:variable name="node2" select="following-sibling::node2[1]" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$node2 != ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="$node2" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>Default</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @Tomalak, If node1 isn't null and node2 is null, no need to update node2 .. node2 must be transformed as null itself .. Can you please update the answer with this condition? I tried but failed .. thank you ..

Comment: You should have stated this requirement in the question.

Comment: Well in my code unless I don't specify to update <node2> with Default text .. it doesn't do that .. But in your code the approach is converse .. So I made heedlessness to explicitly write that requirement ..

Comment: I know .. but I liked the solution as it accomplishes most of my requirement and .. that's enough for me ..  Well. There is really no harm in updating <node2/> but I just wanted to know the possibilities with the code ;)

Comment: There is an answer from me and it may be worth your attention :)

Answer (score 2):

I have modified [Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287740/xslt-code-optimization-how-to-output-the-nodes-refering-to-the-value-of-siblin/2287998#2287998)'s answer and accomplished the requirement ..
As I have mentioned in my question, This code passes node2 as null (if it is null) if the sibling node1 isn't null (and also if there is no sibling node1) ..

This code finally became an alternative to the one I have posted in my Q .. (I don't say it is perfect enough .. but I am glad that I could try .. :-)
And this code is more efficient than mine by some 10-20 msecs .. :-)

Here it goes ..

```
  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node1[.=''] | node2[.='']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="GetOwnValue">
        <xsl:with-param name="node">
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="GetOwnValue">
    <xsl:param name="node"/>
    <xsl:variable name="node2" select="following-sibling::node2[1]|preceding-sibling::node2[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="node1" select="following-sibling::node1[1]|preceding-sibling::node1[1]" />
     <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$node2 != ''">
          <xsl:value-of select="$node2" />
      </xsl:when>
       <xsl:when test="$node!='node1' and ($node1!='' or not(following-sibling::node1[1]|preceding-sibling::node1[1]))"/>
      <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:text>Default</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0 I would do this, but yours is easier to read anyway.

```
<xsl:template match="node1[.='']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="if (following-sibling::node2[.!='']) then following-sibling::node2[.!=''] else if (preceding-sibling::node2[.!='']) then preceding-sibling::node2[.!=''] else 'Default'"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node2[.='']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="if (following-sibling::node1[.!='']) then '' else if (preceding-sibling::node1[.!='']) then '' else 'Default'"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I prefer XSLT 1.0 .. because Microsoft products don't support xslt 2.0 .. thanx for the response anyway .. :-)